# ContentResolver Cursor value returns a NULL In Android Stock OS throws SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider

Tags: android, permission-denied, android-contentresolver, android-external-storage

I trying to receive the video and audio content from Filemanagers like google's FilesGo app and other file manager app, into my application. I using ContentResolver to fetch the media content by using URI,  I gave access permission for necessary run-time permission and declared in AndroidManifest.but the Cursor value returns a NULL value and Security Exception. In Android Stock OS devices like pixel and Motorola, and Nexus. How to resolve this issue?

**Video Parsing logic**

```
private void parseVideoNew(String type, Uri mUri) {
    try {
        //Model Class
        MediaFileInfo mediaFileInfo = new MediaFileInfo();
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                "_id",
                "_display_name",
                "duration",
                "_size"
        };
        try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                        mUri,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                )){
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    // Cache column indices.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Cursor Video Count---=>" + cursor.getCount());
                    // Get values of columns for a given video.
                    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int duration = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
                    String filepath = "";
                    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(mUri.getScheme())) {
                        filepath = getDataColumn(getActivityContext, mUri, null, null);
                    }
                    // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
                    // that represents the media file.
                    try {
                        mediaFileInfo.setFileName(name);
                        mediaFileInfo.setDuration(String.valueOf(duration));
                        mediaFileInfo.setFileType(type);
                        mediaFileInfo.setFilePath(filepath);
                        mediaList.add(mediaFileInfo);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "mediaList size---=>" + mediaList.size() + "," + mediaList.toString());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };
        try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                String value = cursor.getString(column_index);
                if (value.startsWith("content://") || !value.startsWith("/") && !value.startsWith("file://")) {
                    return null;
                }
                return value;
            }
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/content_provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
     </provider>
<activity
            android:name=".activity.Splash"
            android:exported="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- intent filter for sharing multiple files -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Exception is thrown in Device:**
1-*java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{62cfb02 574:com.app.myapp.rc/u0a84} (pid=574, uid=10084) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs*

In GoogleDeveloper's Document also they mentioned Cursor value return Null for the first time of App Launch in devices. does anyone facing this issue. Please help to resolve this issue.

Reference Link:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do with the obtained uri. And you cannot use a FileProvider for an obtained uri.

Comment: `using ContentResolver to fetch the media content by using URI` ? There is nothing in your code that that reads the content of the video or audio file.

Comment: Why are yo using the .DATA column?

Comment: Have to show the Thumbnail and duration.

Comment: @blackapps I need to share the media contents from Gallery with my application. So follow this approach. I digging with this issue a long time.

Comment: Your app does not share. Your app receives a file that is shared from another app. Now please react to all my comments to the point.

Comment: Yes my app want to recieve a file